# Virtualbox relaunching the disk image instead of the server everytime

Tags: virtualbox, grub, ubuntu-11.04

I am on OS X Lion, I am trying to install an ubuntu server (11.04) to a Virtualbox using an .iso disk image I have downloaded. Once I finish the installation (which includes the installation of GRUB by the way) I can log in to my account. But when I close the Virtualbox and open it again it launches the Ubuntu disk image again instead of launching GRUB and going to the server's login screen.

I know as a fact that this is not an issue related to Lion since I had the same issue under OS X Snow Leopard.

Does anyone know how I can install ubuntu server permanently in Virtualbox without having to reinstall everything everytime please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried disconnecting the Ubuntu .iso from the Vm ? Got to Settings->Storage and from there disconnect it.